# Gtk2 Multi Thread gdk_pixbuf_get_from_drawable Questions

Tags: c, multithreading, gtk, gdk

Hi there fellow GTKers

I am in a situation where I am writing a plug in for Firefox which is a GTK2 app. I need to execute `gdk_pixbuf_get_from_drawable`, now this function needs to run on the main thread.

I read this article: http://blogs.operationaldynamics.com/andrew/software/gnome-desktop/gtk-thread-awareness

And learned that to call this from my thread I have to first call:

1. `g_threads_init()` - i dont do this though as i cant find this function defined in `libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0` nor in `libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0`
2. `gdk_threads_init()`
3. `gtk_init(0, null)`
4. `gdk_threads_enter()`
5. `gdk_pixbuf_get_from_drawable(....)`
6. `gdk_threads_leave()`

So this works fine but everytime my user clicks the button to take a screen shot I execute all these functions again. So my questions are:

1. Is it safe to run `gdk_threads_init` multiple times? The thread was never destroyed so i shouldnt have to run it right? but is it safe if i do?
2. Is it ok to run `gtk_init(0, null)` multiple times?

The reason I ask this is because when I test by repeatedlycalling the function typically after second time the app slows down and eventually crash with message:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>
> 0x00007f09382138b4 in XGetImage () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need any of this; Firefox will have done gtk_init for you, and if you're on the main thread you don't need any of that thread stuff. The most you could need, if FF does use GDK thread stuff, would be the enter and leave.

The segfault is most likely caused by an unrelated mistake. Try setting MALLOC_CHECK_=2 and running in gdb, or try running under valgrind, to find memory errors.

Comment: I was helping him out, and I don't think Firefox does `gdk_threads_init` anywhere, if that wasn't done is it ok for me to tell him to do that multiple times in his function? Because I help a lot of addon devs, and they all may call `gdk_threads_init`, and users may have one ore more of these addons installed. So `gdk_threads_init` would get called multiple times. Or should I tell them to call `gdk_threads_init` once per thread? All these C functions are called from WebWorker threads in Firefox addons.

Comment: Or maybe I should file a bug and request Firefox add in `gdk_threads_init` before their `gtk_init` call? As docs say `gdk_threads_init` should go before `gtk_init`, would it be bad if it went after?

Comment: In latest GTK these thread functions are deprecated and you're supposed to do everything on the main thread, which has probably always been best. If FF doesn't call threads init or use enter/leave itself, that's how you have to do it in FF; adding the init wouldn't be enough. So I think you need to get the screenshot code onto the main thread. This is normally done by e.g. adding an idle function to do it (g_idle_add).

Comment: Thanks @Havoc FF is in process of going GTK3. When they do, should i use `g_idle_add` from the thread, or does it have to be used from the main thread?

Comment: I believe you can g_idle_add from your other thread, and the idle then runs on the main thread. If not then you might need to use the variant of idle_add that takes a main context, and manually pass in the context from the main thread. But I think that's what g_idle_add does anyway.

Comment: Thanks @Havoc I will share this information with the students. However g_idle_add does not work in GTK2 apps correct? I tried it and it crashes. :(

Comment: Thanks very much Havoc i think its crashing because `gdk_threads_init` was never called, is that true?

Comment: I don't know without debugging it. I would think Firefox has a way to send tasks to the main thread from another thread, though.

Comment: That's interesting thanks for that note, why is that I'm curious. Becuse I tried hard to send from off the main thread some stuff and thought I got it but when the students go and test it they find it crashes and then im embarassed hahah

Comment: Thank you Havov we are looking into `g_idle_add_full`